# How do I print my functions doc strings with doxygen?

Tags: c, doxygen

I'm using doxygen to document some C code. I have doxygen friendly comments:

```
/**
 * some comment
 *
 * @param a something
 */
```

and my directory structure looks like this:

```
libproject/
    src/
        project.h
        project.c
    docs/
        project.doc.conf
        index.txt
    Makefile
```

I have generated `project.doc.conf` with `doxygen -g project.doc.conf` and configured the `INPUT` tag to be

```
INPUT = index.txt ../src/
```

I've also added a dummy `index.txt`:

```
/*! \mainpage My Personal Index Page
 *
 * \section intro_sec Introduction
 *
 * This is the introduction.
 *
 * \section install_sec Installation
 *
 * \subsection step1 Step 1: Opening the box
 *
 * etc...
 */
```

for testing. When I run:

```
$ doxygen project.doc.conf
```

I get two new folders in `libproject/docs/`: `html` and `latex`. So far, so good.

However when I navigate to `index.html` in my browser I just get the index page and a list of files. I can browse the source but the documentation is missing!

Where is the documentation? Do I have to specify some tags for doxygen to draw it?

Answer (score 0):

You must document each file using:

```
/**
 * @file  project.h
 * @brief some brief description
 */
```

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#structuralcommands